# Using "Elseif" "OR" "And" statement to create label from two fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript

I'm an admittedly novice when it comes to scripting but I have been able to create a basic 'else if' with 'OR' expression to create a label for a fuse feature class I have constructed. I am now trying to combine an additional field into this statement but have been at a lose on how to get there.

In the code shown below I am labeling fuses by assigning a number (1, 2,3) based on its phasing code (A, AB, ABC); respectively. I now also want to assign an "I"(installed) or a "P"(proposed), preferably in bold, that corresponds with my "Construction Status" field.

```
Function FindLabel ( [phasingcode] )
Dim a
If [phasingcode] = "A" OR [phasingcode] = "B"  OR  [phasingcode] = "C" then
    a = "(1)"
Elseif [phasingcode] = "AB" OR [phasingcode] = "BA" OR  [phasingcode] = "AC" OR [phasingcode] = "CA" OR [phasingcode] = "BC" OR  [phasingcode] = "CB" then
  a = "(2)"
Else
 a = "(3)"
end if 
FindLabel = a
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the "Construction Status" field in the Function FindLabel then create a "b" variable that you fill using the same logic you used for your "a" variable and change the FindLabel = a to FindLabel = a&b

See below for what it could look like (sorry, no time to write it properly...)

```
Function FindLabel ( [phasingcode],[Construction Status] )
Dim a
Dim b

If [phasingcode] = "A" OR [phasingcode] = "B"  OR  [phasingcode] = "C" then
  a = "(1)"
Elseif [phasingcode] = "AB" OR [phasingcode] = "BA" OR  [phasingcode] = "AC" OR [phasingcode] = "CA" OR [phasingcode] = "BC" OR  [phasingcode] = "CB" then
  a = "(2)"
Else
  a = "(3)"
end if

If [Construction Status] = ... then
  b = ...
Elseif [Construction Status] = ... then
  b = ...
Else
  b = ...
end if

FindLabel = a&b
End Function
```

For the bold part you could try `FindLabel = a & "<BOL>" & b & "</BOL>"` but I didn't try that...